# RewriteRule loop, content negotiation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have made the rounds through Stack Overflow, and I haven't found an answer to my question (or at least I didn't recognize it), so I decided to open my own question.

I am trying to set up a content negotiation system to serve HTML by default and when requested and RDF/XML when requested. The URI would be a non-information source. The user would go to the URI and it would redirect the user to the appropriate file based on the request. For example:

```
GET: http://example.com/ldExamples/catalog_001
Accept: application/rdf+xml
```

This should result in a redirect to `http://example.com/ldExamples/catalog_001.rdf`

I have tried a couple of approaches to this. All of the following code was adapted from [W3C's Best Practice Recipes for Publishing RDF Vocabularies](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-vocab-pub/). Here's the first attempt:

```
# Turn off MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

# Directive to ensure *.rdf files served as appropriate content type,
# if not present in main apache config
AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf

# Rewrite engine setup
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ldExamples

# Rewrite rule 2: to serve HTML content from class or prop URIs if     requested
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*  (text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [R=303]

# Rewrite rule 3: to serve RDF content is requested
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.rdf [R=303]

# Choose the default response
# ---------------------------

# Rewrite rule 4: to serve RDF/XML content by default
#RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.rdf [R=303]

# Rewrite rules to serve HTML content by default
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [R=303]
```

When trying:

```
GET: http://example.com/ldExamples/catalog_001/
```

I receive `http://example.com/ldExamples/catalog_001.html.html`

With:

```
GET: http://example.com/ldExamples/catalog_001/
Accept: application/rdf+xml
```

I receive `http://example.com/ldExamples/catalog_001.html.rdf.html`

I know this has to do with looping. I tried adding `L` to `[R=303]`. I later found out I was receiving a 500 internal error because of the loop as well.

To debug further, I tried removing the loop and targeting a URL directly:

```
# Turn off MultiViews
Options -MultiViews

# Directive to ensure *.rdf files served as appropriate content type,
# if not present in main apache config
AddType application/rdf+xml .rdf

# Rewrite engine setup
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ldExamples

# Rewrite rule 2: to serve HTML content from class or prop URIs if  requested
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} !application/rdf\+xml.*(text/html|application/xhtml\+xml)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/xhtml\+xml [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla/.*
RewriteRule ^catalog_001$ catalog_001.html [R=303]

# Rewrite rule 3: to serve RDF content is requested
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/rdf\+xml
RewriteRule ^catalog_001$ catalog_001.rdf [R=303]

# Choose the default response
# ---------------------------

# Rewrite rule 4: to serve RDF/XML content by default
# RewriteRule ^catalog_001$ catalog_001.rdf [R=303]

# Rewrite rules to serve HTML content by default
RewriteRule ^catalog_001$ catalog_001.html [R=303]
```

This returns `http://examples.com/ldExamples/catalog_001.html` regardless of `Accept` request. I tried adding `L` to the `[R=303]`, but it also resulted in a 500 internal error.

Ultimately, I would like for some kind of variable setup, because I would like to serve multiple URIs and files.